# Can I use an external file for system.web config similar to file attribute for appSettings

Tags: c#, web-config

I am hoping to separate the Identity config in the system.web section of my web.config and put it in a separate file so that I don't have to check in to source control the username/password being used.

Is this possible? It looks like the file attribute doesn't work for the system.web section and even if the configSource attribute would work, I wouldn't want to have all of the system.web config section in a different file.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find out if there is a way to use the file attribute on `system.web` Jacques? We're trying to put our `globalization` config into a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more research has revealed that while we can't use `configSource` or `file` attributes on the `<System.Web>` section, you can use it on the tags within it.

For example, I wanted to move our `globalization` settings out of `web.config` into `globalization.config`, and so we changed our web config from this:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
    <!-- Other settings removed -->
</system.web>
```

to this

```
<system.web>
    <globalization configSource="globalization.config" />
    <!-- Other settings removed -->
</system.web>
```